# Hashtable in Class / Print to console

Tags: c#, class, hashtable

I have an object class "Character" with a hashtable inside of it for weapons. I'm just trying to print the weapon to the console when I print the character stats for approval, but having a hard time figuring out a simple way to do this.

Advs is the Character object array, if there's any information I forgot to include please let me know, first time posting. The i.weapons.value is what I'm trying to fix, everything else prints to console correctly, that gives me strange values that look like pointers to the hashtable on print.

```
    private static void ChStats(Character[] Advs) {
        foreach (Character i in Advs) {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\nClass: {1}\nLevel: {2}\nHealth: {3}\nStrength: {4}\nIntellect: {5}\nAgility: {6}\nSanity: {7}\nWeapon: {8}\n", 
                i.name, i.characterClass, i.lvl, i.hlth, i.str, i.itl, i.agi, i.san, i.weapons.value);
        }
```

as an addition, the hash table contains two values for each weapon wNme and dmg. The code below works, but seem so sloppy, hopefully there's a better way to accomplish this.

```
        foreach (Character i in Advs) {
            string[] weaponDesc = new string[10];
            int n = 0;
            foreach (Weapon w in i.weapons.Values)
            {
                weaponDesc[n++] = w.wNme;
            }
            // this version works but with extra commas
            //Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\nClass: {1}\nLevel: {2}\nHealth: {3}\nStrength: {4}\nIntellect: {5}\nAgility: {6}\nSanity: {7}\nWeapon: {8}\n",
            //    i.name, i.characterClass, i.lvl, i.hlth, i.str, i.itl, i.agi, i.san, string.Join(", ",  weaponDesc));
            // better but more complex
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\nClass: {1}\nLevel: {2}\nHealth: {3}\nStrength: {4}\nIntellect: {5}\nAgility: {6}\nSanity: {7}\nWeapon: {8}\n",
                i.name, i.characterClass, i.lvl, i.hlth, i.str, i.itl, i.agi, i.san, string.Join(", ",  weaponDesc.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))));
```

Comment: Hashtable doesn't have a nice ToString, but you can throw something together yourself. How would you like it to look?

Comment: I thought it would be like calling an element from an array, I have one solution, but it seems really convoluted, esp if I'm going to call the weapon values for dmg it contains often during "game" play.

Comment: Of course you can avoid that array, just put that field-selection into the LINQy part

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the very very old Hashtable class and not the newer stronger typed `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class? Also, if you are using C# 6 (Visual Studio 2015 or newer) you might want to use the string interpolation feature to make your code easier to read. `var weapons = string.Join(", ",  weaponDesc.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))); Console.WriteLine($"Name: {i.name}\nClass: {i.characterClass}\nLevel: {i.lvl}\nHealth: {i.hlth}\nStrength: {i.str}\nIntellect: {i.itl}\nAgility: {i.agi}\nSanity: {i.san}\nWeapon: {weapons}\n");`

Comment: Hashtables, which aren't generic, usually have to box and unbox data. Use a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which is more efficient and you get type safety..

Comment: I'm new to programming so just going with what I've learned so far, hence the outdated information I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Generics typed HashSet class is a better choice.

```
HashSet<Weapon> Weapons;
Weapons = new HashSet<Weapon>();
Weapons.Add(new Weapon()); // Assume this is created and populated elsewhere
StringBuilder SBText = new StringBuilder(64 + (Weapons.Count * 8)); // An approximation of the eventual string length
SBText.Append(@"Class, Level, etc...");
// Cryptic but compact Lync method (Not my favourite)
Weapons.Where(Wpn => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Wpn.name)).ToList().ForEach(delegate (Weapon Wpn) { if (SBText.Length > 0) { SBText.Append(@", "); } SBText.Append(Wpn.name); });
// Explicit code method
foreach (Weapon Wpn in Weapons)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Wpn.name))
    {
        if (SBText.Length > 0) { SBText.Append(@", "); }
        SBText.Append(Wpn.name);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(SBText.ToString());
```